# docker-compose run mysql:latest failing with caching_sha2_password

Tags: mysql, docker-compose

Localhost: aarch64

I am attempting to set up a test environment and encountered an issue connecting to the 'mysql:latest' container from another Docker container

I have a MySQL image, and when I run it standalone, it functions as expected.

```
Inside mysql container: 
bash-4.4# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.2.0 for Linux on aarch64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

Local machine: 
docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql                                                                                  
7ebe5aee548a6a22dad824f3160f224390478b09b44fc546a6781f4ef1702497

** 
❯ docker exec -it some-mysql bash                                                                                                                           
bash-4.4#

bash-4.4# mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 10
Server version: 8.2.0 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2023, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

It appears to work as expected.

But when I want to run exact similar container from docker-compose it doesn't work.

```
❯ cat docker-compose.yaml                                                                                                                                   
version: '3'
services:
  jenkins:
    container_name: jenkins
    image: jenkins/jenkins
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - $PWD/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
    networks:
      - net
  remote_host:
    container_name: remote-host
    image: remote-host
    build:
      context: centos7
    networks:
      - net
  db_host:
    container_name: db
    image: mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234
    volumes:
      - "$PWD/db_data:/var/lib/mysql"
    networks:
      - net
networks:
  net:
```

Steps:
(remote-host mysql client version:
`mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.68-MariaDB, for Linux (aarch64) using readline 5.1`)

1. Connect to remote-host

`docker exec -it remote-host bash`

2. Connect to mysql:

`mysql -u root -h db_host -p`

```
[root@b07a346bc579 /]# mysql -u root -h db_host -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2059 (HY000): Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: 
/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so: cannot open shared object file: No 
such file or directory
```

3. It also don't works as from remote-host as well as from db container (which is the same image I ran in standalone)

Extra notes. What I did try already:

1. Check if plugin is installed and in standalone version was able to find it running `SHOW PLUGINS;` as admin.
2. Set different types of password in different manner in docker-compose.
3. Ran docker compose with:

`command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password`

And it didn't work as well. mysql logs said: `mysql_native_password` depricated use `new plugin`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You've got a old MariaDB client that didn't have MySQL's caching_sha2_password implemented at the time. `--default-authentication-plugin` only affects newly created users. `ALTER USER root@localhost WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password` might be the option if you want to keep the same client. [ref](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.2/en/alter-user.html)

Comment: @danblack `ALTER...` query resolved problem! TY